# Table Column Resize Salesforce lightning slds

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to apply the resizable column for table by following the solution provided here.

http://platformevangelist.com/deep-dive-into-lightning-design-system-table-column-resizing/

**Issue**: When the column resize handle is dragged the first time its not working but works from the second drag.

Div tag :

```
<div class="slds-resizable">
<input type="range" min="20" max="1000" class="slds-resizable__input slds-assistive-text" id="cell-resize-handle-602" tabindex="0" />
    <span class="slds-resizable__handle" onmousedown="{!c.calculateWidth}" ondrag="{!c.setNewWidth}">
        <span class="slds-resizable__divider"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Do I need to add any flags to the events "mousedown" and "Drag".

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little bit outdated, but I just spent an hour on this problem and found a solution, `draggable="true"` should be added to resizable span element.

```
<span class="slds-resizable__handle" onmousedown="{!c.calculateWidth}" ondrag="{!c.setNewWidth}" draggable="true">
```